# How do I restrict the range of an interpolating function in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have a numerical solution for a differential equation. I know that the gray dotted solution is unphysical. Is there a way I can tell mathematica to ignore the gray dotted solution (e.g. restrict the interpolating function to values between 0 and 1)? (Later on, I want to do operations on this solution, and I don't want the gray solution to contribute)
[image]

I tried to use `WhenEvent`, but I get an error message.

```
sa = NDSolve[{3/2 (a'[t]/a[t])^2 + 
     a'[t]/a[t] vdot[t]/v[t] - ωa/8 vdot[t]^2 == 
    1/4 ρ0/a[t]^3, a[todaya] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[a[t] > 1, "StopIntegration"]}, a, {t, EQfraca, todaya}]

aa = Plot[Evaluate[a[t] /. sa], {t, EQfraca, todaya}, 
   PlotRange -> {{EQfraca, todaya}, {mina, maxa}}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Gray, Dotted}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "a (t)"}];
```

Comment: Hi! You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Many symbols are undefined in the code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of definitions for several functions and constants, I chose

```
v[t] = 1; vdot[t] = 1; todaya = .8; EQfraca = .5; ωa = 1; ρ0 = 1; mina = 0.9; maxa = 1.3;
```

`NDSolve` then yields two `InterpolatingFunction`s

```
(* {{a -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.5, 0.8}}, <>]}, 
    {a -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.5, 0.8}}, <>]}} *)
```

which in turn yields two curves.

[image]

(Note that I changed `PlotStyle` to `{{Gray, Dotted}, {Red, Thick}}` for consistency with the figure in the question.)  Because the two `InterpolatingFunction`s are distinct, simply do not use the one you do not want.

By the way, `WhenEvent[a[t] > 1, "StopIntegration"]` has no effect, because the upper curve starts at `a[t] ==1`, so no crossing occurs.  To trigger it, use `a[t] > 1.000001`, for instance.  This does not eliminate `Gray` curve, but it does make it very short.

Addendum: In answer to a comment below, the `InterpolatingFunction` which is less than `1` can be picked out by, for instance,

```
If[First@(a[todaya - .01] /. sa) < 1, First@sa, Last@sa]
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. =)
I wrote {say,sa2}= NDSolve[....]
sa1 covers one solution, say2 covers the other solution.

Comment: Yes, that works.  If you wish to automate the process, try something like `sa[[Which[First@(a[.7] /. sa) < 1, 1, Last@(a[.7] /. sa) < 1, 2]]]`